# python - best approach when analysing scraped data

Tags: python

Newbie here. I have managed to put together a script which scrapes some information from a website. This happens daily, and the data is saved on a csv file. content of each file is similar to this:

```
date, ticker, company name, momentum indicator, other ratios....
2016-08-19, GSK, GlaxoSmithKline, 42, ....
2016-08-19, RDSB, Royal Dutch Shell, 98, .....
....
```

I have accumulated 3 months worth of daily data, so around 80 files. (Every row in the file has the same date and then the different shares).
What I would like to do now is to check, on a share by share basis, the evolution of the momentum indicator and other ratios.

for example, I think I should end up with a series of lists such as

```
GSK_momentum_indicator = (42, 43, 38, 47,...) 
RDSB_momentum_indicator = (98, 91, 77, 79,...)
```

Now, as a newbie, I have 2 questions:
1) what do you think is the best approach for this? Is it using lists, dictionaries, anything else?
2) **how** did you decide the above? are there guidelines for which strategy to use? is there a good resource I can read as a newbie to learn more about this subject?

thanks!

PS. in case it makes a difference, I'm using python 3.5.2.

Comment: Check out [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: Yes. Pandas is definitively the direction. I gave you an upvote. But I sometime just be confused, that how we answer such questions. Leaving "check out pandas", will be down voted by others massively...

Answer (score 1):

In order to process the data you've collected, you could use one of the python modules, `csv` or `pandas`. The `csv` module is used to read/write data from/to csv files and then you can convert the data into python lists and dictionaries and use accordingly. For detailed docs go [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

But if you have large dataset then you should go for `pandas` which a specialized tool for data analysis. The `pandas.read_csv` function takes the name of the csv file as argument and returns a DataFrame object on which you can perform various operation. For detailed docs go [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).